# What are indivisible changes in concurrent applications?

Tags: c++, c++11, concurrency

I have just started reading about how to write concurrent application using thread library of C++11 standard. What I don't understand is if I want to handle problematic race conditions there is an option of redesigning data structure in such way that the modifications are series of INDIVISIBLE CHANGES?

What does indivisible changes mean?

Comment: So are you trying to say that atomic operations and indivisible changes are the same?

Comment: @user225008: atomic _literally_ means indivisible. But atomic operations also include atomic reads, which obviously are not changes.

Comment: Ok Thank you. I read about the atomic operations and I think I got the idea now.